# How to apply custom domain to Azure Linux server

Tags: azure

New to Azure.

I need to point a custom domain to a Linux based Resource Group (Not sure if Resource Group is correct nomenclature).

Here are my steps.

1. I created a new Linux Virtual machine.  (works great!)
2. It has a built in url: http://mysite.cloudapp.net/.  This was
   provided during the creation of the resource by Azure, is publicly
   available, and works great. I want to customize the url and could
   not find any DNS type settings for this particular resource.
3. In order to customize the domain I created a new Web App and pointed
   it to the MySite Resource group, purchased a new domain
   (MyAwesomeSite.com) within Azure and associated it to
   the Web App. My hope here was that the new domain would magically
   point to the MySite resource, it didn't.
4. When I go to the new url (MyAwesomeSite.com) I see a standard 'Web app successfully
   created' message not the Linux server.

Can someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding some things. Resource groups are simply a container and don't have runtime implications. A Web App is a completely different resource from a VM, it is just an self-contained website, and doesn't affect the VM at all.

To give your VM a custom domain name: make sure your Linux VM has a public IP address, and then go to your registrar and create an A record to that IP Address with host @. Then create a CNAME record with host www to whatever the URL of the machine given by Azure is.

This should work although you may need to change your Apache or Nginx config.

Comment: My situation is: my domain is bought via Azure. How can I go to "registrar"? Where should I add A record adn CNAME record?

Answer (score 0):

Ok 2 things here, you have 2 resources here 
1. A Linux VM
2. A Web App - which is a PAAS based service

Both provide a default URL from azure

your site could be at either , I am not sure where but lets wager that you have it at the LinuxVM which has this default url all you need to do is go to your domain provider and create a CName which points to the "Azure Default URL" of this VM and then go to the Dashboard->Configure->Manage Domains and provide the CNAME here.

These steps do well if you are using manage.windowsazure.com , if you are using the portal.azure.com then select your app or the VM - go to settings->Routing->customdomains & SSL settings.

This link should be able to help you http://candordeveloper.com/2013/04/16/how-to-forward-a-godaddy-domain-to-azure/

Know more about VM and Webapps 
1. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm/
2. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-dotnet-create-visual-studio-powershell/